# div size not working

Tags: html, css

can anybody tell me why my divs don't scale to the size prescribed, and show its background? Thank you.

My code:

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 
html, body {

    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#wrapper-image {
 
}

#header-title {
 left: 0;
 align: center;
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;

}

#header-image {
 width:1280px;
 height:1280px;
 background-image: url("Westminster.jpg");
 object-fit: contain;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href = "main.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />

<head>
 <title> Big Oof </title>
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class = "wrapper">
 <div class = "header-image">
 <div class = "header-title">
 
 
  <h1 style="text-align:center"> Title </h1>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
 

 
 
</body>
```

westminster.jpg is a jpeg file of a picture of The Houses of Parliament from The River Thames. Thank you!

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` can only be used to `table-cell` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set `class` so in **css** you need put `.` instead `#`

I recommand you learn about `selector` in css:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 }

 
html, body {

    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper-image {
 
}

.header-title {
 left: 0;
 align: center;
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;

}

.header-image {
 width:1280px;
 height:1280px;
 background-image: url("Westminster.jpg");
 object-fit: contain;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href = "main.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />

<head>
 <title> Big Oof </title>
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class = "wrapper">
 <div class = "header-image">
 <div class = "header-title">
 
 
  <h1 style="text-align:center"> Title </h1>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
 

 
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using `#` (id selector) in css, but class in html
2. `url("Westminster.jpg");` does not seem to be proper URL to image. Are you sure that it's on root?

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

 
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header-title {
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.header-image {
 width:1280px;
 height:1280px;
 background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/1280x1280");
 object-fit: contain;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href = "main.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />

<head>
 <title> Big Oof </title>
 

</head>
<body>
 <div class = "wrapper">
    <div class = "header-image">
      <div class = "header-title">
        <h1 style="text-align:center"> Title </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How do you know his image isn't working for him, when it is stored locally?

Comment: @SirExotic Because usually all images are separated from working files in different dir, like `/images`, `/uploads`, etc.

Comment: That could be the case, but the initial reason why he could not see his image was because he was using `#`'s instead of `.`'s.

Comment: @SirExotic And that's the first bullet point in my answer? Is this seems wrong to you...?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that that was wrong, I just don't understand why you would assume his image is in the wrong place, because the reason why he couldn't see his image was because of that other mistake. That's all.

Comment: Thanks. It works, though I have more to do. Thank you!

Comment: @SimplySnap Don't forget to accept answer if it answers your question